# Filtering Multiple Strings in R

Tags: r, filtering

With filter function I can filter one country, but I want to filter five at the same time.

Afghanistan, Iraq, Nigeria, Yemen and India.

I tried to us OR but it did not work.

Thanks!

```
  gtd %>%
    select(country_txt) %>%
    filter(country_txt== ("Afghanistan"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grepl()` here with a regex alternation:

```r
countries <- c("Afghanistan", "Iraq", "Nigeria", "Yemen", "India")
regex <- paste0("^(?:", paste(countries, collapse="|"), ")$")

gtd %>%
    select(country_txt) %>%
    filter(grepl(regex, country_txt))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `%in%` operator:

```
  gtd %>%
    filter(country_txt %in% c("Afghanistan","Iraq","Nigeria","Yemen","India"))
```